# Web API / SharePoint

Tags: 2013, security, custom-web-app

In an attempt to abstract the process of accessing SharePoint data, I would like to create a Web API application that can run server-side code (think, *SP* objects).

What are some *best practices* for accomplishing this?  The question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82460/sharepoint-2013-asp-net-web-api) seems to discuss what *should not* be done but doesn't really indicate what *can* or *should* be done.

Such a Web API application would need to know the security context from SharePoint so that security trimming takes place.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen this http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC404

Comment: I have not...but I will certainly take a look.